# Always quote plain version with mutt

Tags: quote, reply, mutt

I read mails with mutt and a lot of people send mail with both plain and html version.
I prefer to see html version with elinks in some cases so I had to set text/html as my preferred alternative.

However, when replying, the quote is infamous (a lot of ugly characters) so I'd like to use the text/plain version in the quote.

Two linked questions emerge:

- is it possible to have alternative_order option set depending on the folder
- is it possible to quote the text version of the email even if the mail was seen in html

This question has also bee asked on http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/75#comment_28 without reply.

Answer (score 0):

Using the result from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248871/revert-all-mutt-custom-config) related to mutt configuration, I can think of a solution to set the alternative_order:

Suppose, I prefer to see plain text on folder1, html elsewhere:

```
#this reset all conf when changing folder
set my_reset_source=`~/.dotfiles/mutt/reset.sh ~/.dotfiles/mutt/*.config > /tmp/mutt-reset`
folder-hook . source /tmp/mutt-reset
folder-hook . source ~/.dotfiles/mutt/html_prefered
folder-hook folder1 source ~/.dotfiles/mutt/plain_prefered
```

with ~/.dotfiles/mutt/plain_prefered, being:

```
alternative_order text/plain
```

This solution, however does not answer the other part of the question: how to always quote the plain text version.