# Revert all mutt custom config

Tags: mutt

I am trying to setup a two (maybe more) mailboxes in mutt with very different settings.
I have setup folder-hooks for each but it custom settings are not fully the same.

I wonder how to reset all custom settings setup for one mailbox before applying settings from the other.

The setup is:

```
.muttrc:
   some custom config...
   mre custom config...
   folder-hook home source .mutt/home.config
   folder-hook work source .mutt/work.config
```

I'd like to reset all configs setup by home.config when I apply work.config (but keep general config setup by .muttrc so `reset all` is too much).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Own answer:

Create a script `reset.sh` like:

```
grep -E -h -v '^(#.*)?$' $@ |  sed -E 's/(.*)=.*/\1/; s/^(un)?set/reset/g; /macro/d'
```

and as Adam suggested, in the main conf:

```
set my_reset_source=`~/.mutt/reset.sh ~/.mutt/*.config > /tmp/mutt-reset`
folder-hook . source /tmp/mutt-reset
folder-hook home source ~/.mutt/home.config
folder-hook work source ~/.mutt/work.config
```

Comment: Yeah, something along those lines should work. Reinventing the mutt config file parser wheel here is unfortunately unavoidable.  BTW I think it should be `sed -E` not `sed -e`, but with GNU sed you don't need the `-e` or even two separate `sed` invocations: `sed 'command1; command2'`

Comment: unfortunately Id on't see how to reset macro, so I'll simply have to remove any mention of macro

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
folder-hook . source .mutt/default.config
```

before the other two `folder-hook`s, as stated in [section 3.5 of the manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/manual-3.html#ss3.5).

Comment: this won't undo the specific of work.config when I switch to home.config

Comment: It will if `default.config` contains the correct `reset` commands.  AFAICK mutt doesn't have a built-in way of automatically resetting everything within a given config file, so you will have to build `default.config` appropriately via a technique like the one @kamaradclimber suggests.